# Does Server Sent Events Traffic contribute to Heroku autoscaling?

Tags: node.js, heroku, autoscaling, server-sent-events, dyno

I have a NodeJS application running on Heroku that uses server sent events (SSE). In the Heroku documentation I saw:

`The autoscaling algorithm does not include WebSocket traffic in its calculations.`

I was curious if this was also the case for SSE traffic?

Looking at the heroku documentation yielded nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with Heroku support that is does count towards autoscaling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).